# Fortran derived types containing pointers to be accessible from C

Tags: c, pointers, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding, derived-types

I have a Fortran code with many derived types containing pointers. I am writing a C++ code which needs to access these variables. I cannot rewrite these derived types without the pointers as they are used in hundreds of different places all over the Fortran code.

Below is a sample code:

```
module simple
use  iso_c_binding

TYPE,bind(C) :: SIMPLEF
INTEGER :: A
INTEGER, POINTER :: B, C(:)
END TYPE SIMPLEF

end module simple
```

I need to access the SIMPLEF derived type from C. I know I cannot use it as it is, since Fortran pointers cannot be in a derived type if that is supposed to be accessible from C. Is there any kind of workaround?

EXTENSION: As an extension to the previous problem (resolved thanks to IanH), I have derived types which have as members derived types themselves. Example below:

```
TYPE COMPLEXF
  INTEGER :: X
  TYPE (SIMPLEF) :: Y
END TYPE COMPLEXF
```

Would I need to create for COMPLEXF, subroutines for each member of Y, i.e. SETY_A, QUERYY_A, SETY_B, QUERYY_BSIZE, QUERYY_B etc.? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I think it is a time for a separate question.

Comment: I did now [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29243820/4572020)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write some interoperable accessor procedures in Fortran that operate on the derived type and expose the necessary variables to the C++ code.  This is very similar to how general C++ code interacts with private member variables of a class.

You can use the C address of an object of type SIMPLEF as an opaque handle in the C++ code - the type in Fortran does not have to have the BIND(C) attribute to allow objects of that type to be passed to C_LOC (though objects of that type will need to have the TARGET attribute).

For array data, you may need to provide several entry points for the data getters, to allow appropriate coordination of the memory buffer used to transfer the data from Fortran to C.

```
MODULE simple
  IMPLICIT NONE
  ! An example of an non-interoperable type (no BIND(C)).
  TYPE :: SIMPLEF
    INTEGER :: A
    ! Note that given the problem description, the component B 
    ! appears to have value semantics.  If so, as of Fortran 2003 
    ! this should be an ALLOCATABLE component.  Because it is 
    ! a pointer component, we will default initialize it to 
    ! help avoid its pointer association status becoming 
    ! inadvertently undefined 
    INTEGER, POINTER :: B(:) => NULL()
  END TYPE SIMPLEF
CONTAINS
  FUNCTION GetHandle() RESULT(handle) BIND(C, NAME='GetHandle')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR, C_LOC
    TYPE(C_PTR) :: handle
    TYPE(SIMPLEF), POINTER :: p
    !***
    ! For the sake of example we are exposing an interface that 
    ! allows client code to create an object.  Perhaps in your 
    ! case the object already exists and its lifetime is managed 
    ! in some other way, in which case:
    !
    !   handle = C_LOC(existing_object_with_target_attribute)
    !
    ! and you are done - no need for ReleaseHandle.
    ALLOCATE(p)
    ! Perhaps some constructory sort of stuff here?
    p%A = 666
    ! Use the C address of the object as an opaque handle.
    handle = C_LOC(p)
  END FUNCTION GetHandle

  ! If you create objects, you need to be able to destroy them.
  SUBROUTINE ReleaseHandle(handle) BIND(C, NAME='ReleaseHandle')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR, C_F_POINTER
    TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: handle
    TYPE(SIMPLEF), POINTER :: p
    !***
    CALL C_F_POINTER(handle, p)
    DEALLOCATE(p)
  END SUBROUTINE ReleaseHandle

  SUBROUTINE SetA(handle, a) BIND(C, NAME='SetA')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY:  &
        C_PTR, C_F_POINTER, C_INT
    TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: handle
    INTEGER(C_INT), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: a  
    TYPE(SIMPLEF), POINTER :: p
    !***
    CALL C_F_POINTER(handle, p)
    p%A = a
  END SUBROUTINE SetA

  FUNCTION QueryA(handle) RESULT(a) BIND(C, NAME='QueryA')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY:  &
        C_PTR, C_F_POINTER, C_INT
    TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: handle
    INTEGER(C_INT) :: a  
    TYPE(SIMPLEF), POINTER :: p
    !***
    CALL C_F_POINTER(handle, p)
    a = p%A
  END FUNCTION QueryA

  SUBROUTINE SetB(handle, data, data_size) BIND(C, NAME='SetB')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY:  &
        C_PTR, C_F_POINTER, C_INT
    TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: handle
    INTEGER(C_INT), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: data_size
    INTEGER(C_INT), INTENT(IN) :: data(data_size)
    TYPE(SIMPLEF), POINTER :: p
    !***
    CALL C_F_POINTER(handle, p)
    ! Allocate p%B to appropriate size.
    !
    ! Assuming here the pointer association status of p%B is always 
    ! defined or dissociated, never undefined.  This is much easier 
    ! with allocatable components.
    IF (ASSOCIATED(p%B)) THEN
      IF (SIZE(p%B) /= data_size) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(p%B)
        ALLOCATE(p%B(data_size))
      END IF
    ELSE
      ALLOCATE(p%B(data_size))
    END IF
    p%B = data
  END SUBROUTINE SetB

  SUBROUTINE QueryBSize(handle, data_size) BIND(C, NAME='QueryBSize')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY:  &
        C_PTR, C_F_POINTER, C_INT
    TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: handle
    INTEGER(C_INT), INTENT(OUT) :: data_size
    TYPE(SIMPLEF), POINTER :: p
    !***
    CALL C_F_POINTER(handle, p)
    ! See comments about assumed association status above.
    IF (ASSOCIATED(p%B)) THEN
      data_size = SIZE(p%B, KIND=C_INT)
    ELSE
      data_size = 0_C_INT
    END IF
  END SUBROUTINE QueryBSize

  SUBROUTINE QueryBData(handle, data) BIND(C, NAME='QueryBData')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY:  &
        C_PTR, C_F_POINTER, C_INT
    TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: handle
    INTEGER(C_INT), INTENT(OUT) :: data(*)
    TYPE(SIMPLEF), POINTER :: p
    !***
    CALL C_F_POINTER(handle, p)
    ! See comments about assumed association status above.
    IF (ASSOCIATED(p%B)) THEN
      data(:SIZE(p%B)) = p%B
    ELSE
      ! Someone is being silly.
    END IF
  END SUBROUTINE QueryBData

  ! ...etc...
END MODULE simple

//~~~~~~
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void* GetHandle();
extern "C" void ReleaseHandle(void* handle);
extern "C" void SetA(void* handle, int a);
extern "C" int QueryA(void* handle);
extern "C" void SetB(void* handle, const int* data, int data_size);
extern "C" void QueryBSize(void* handle, int* data_size);
extern "C" void QueryBData(void *handle, int *data);

class SimpleF
{
private:
  void *handle;
public:
  SimpleF() 
  { 
    handle = GetHandle(); 
  }

  ~SimpleF() 
  { 
    ReleaseHandle(handle); 
  }

  void SetA(int a) 
  { 
    ::SetA(handle, a); 
  }

  int QueryA()
  { 
    return ::QueryA(handle); 
  }

  void SetB(const std::vector<int>& b)
  {
     ::SetB(handle, &b[0], b.size());
  }

  std::vector<int> QueryB()
  {
    // Get the data size, construct a suitable buffer, populate the buffer.
    int data_size;
    ::QueryBSize(handle, &data_size);
    if (data_size == 0) return std::vector<int>();

    std::vector<int> data(data_size);
    ::QueryBData(handle, &data[0]);
    return data;
  }
};

int main()
{
  SimpleF x;
  x.SetA(99);
  std::cout << x.QueryA() << std::endl;

  std::vector<int> testvector(2,100);
  x.SetB(testvector);
  std::cout << x.QueryB()[0] << ' ' << x.QueryB()[1] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If your compiler supports the features added to the language with TS29113 "Further Interoperability of Fortran with C", then interoperable procedures can have pointer arguments, which may may simplify writing those accessors.  It is intended that the features introduced with that TS will become part of the base language with the next standard revision.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and elegant solution. I am using gfortran which I can see has a partial implementation of TS29113. I am going to try your solution and report back. Apart from a Fortran pointer I also have array of pointers in the SIMPLEF derived type, so I will need to add SHAPE to the C_F_POINTER call for that variable - that may cause an issue if it is a dynamic array on the C++ side. Thanks again!

Comment: I tested it now and it works perfectly - I just had to do some small changes to the `FUNCTION QueryA`, i.e. remove `RESULT(a)` and the line `INTEGER(C_INT), INTENT(OUT) :: a` and add instead `INTEGER(C_INT) :: QueryA` as otherwise I would an error complaining about `a` in `RESULT(a)` being a dummy argument.

Comment: Sorry, I answered too soon. With your example I am able to change values to p%a, but that is an integer. My problem is to modify p%B (integer pointer) or p%C (array of integer pointers). If I try `SUBROUTINE SetB(handle, b) BIND(C, NAME='SetB')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY:  &
        C_PTR, C_F_POINTER, C_INT
    TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: handle
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN), POINTER :: b
    TYPE(SIMPLEF), POINTER :: p
    !***
    CALL C_F_POINTER(handle, p)
    p%B = b
  END SUBROUTINE SetB` then it will give me the expected error

Comment: Continuing, the error is `Error: Variable 'b' at (1) cannot have the POINTER attribute because procedure 'setb' is BIND(C)`

Comment: I modified the soubroutine so that the pointer p%B points to target b from C++ but that causes a crash. `SUBROUTINE SetB(handle, b) BIND(C, NAME='SetB')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY:  &
        C_PTR, C_F_POINTER, C_INT
    TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: handle
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN), TARGET :: b
    TYPE(SIMPLEF), POINTER :: p
    CALL C_F_POINTER(handle, p)
    p%B => b
  END SUBROUTINE SetB`

Comment: The spurious INTENT(OUT) on the function result definition was a copy-pasta error by me.  I will edit it out later.  The error with the pointer argument suggests incomplete TS29113 support.  With the set operation on the pointer component, are you trying to change what thing the Fortran pointer points at, or are you trying to change the the value of the thing that the pointer currently points at?

Comment: Actually it would be enough to change the value of the thing that the Fortran pointer points at. This is the current status of TS29113 support for gfortran (assuming the link is updated)  [https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/TS29113Status](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/TS29113Status)

Comment: Edits made with additional example.  Note that in your original Fortran code you don't have an array of pointers - no such concept exists in Fortran.  The component C (B in my modified example) is a pointer component to a rank one array.  One pointer, pointing at one array, with that array having many data elements.

Comment: Many thanks for your time - I have now tested the code by adding the following to main in C++ `std::vector<int> testvector (2,100); x.SetB(testvector); std::cout << x.QueryB()[0] <<" " << x.QueryB()[1]<<endl;` however this crashes. I checked in Fortran and the vector is passed correctly. Even inside `std::vector<int> QueryB()` I can see that just before return data command, the value of the vector is correct. Not sure why it crashes when calling `x.QueryB()[0]`.  - Doing some further testing, the crash appears to come from `::QueryBSize(handle, &data_size);`.Thanks again

Comment: I just tried it with gfortran/gcc 4.9.2 and ifort 15.0.2/msvc++ 16.0, and after adding in a missing `RESULT(handle)` on the function statement for the GetHandle function and some #includes on the C++ side, it works for me.

Comment: The crashing is due to some compiler issue, if I compile using `gfortran -c b.f90; g++ b.o a.cpp -lgfortran; ./a.exe` it runs fine, while if I make the fortran file a dll, then it crashes `gfortran.exe b.f90 -shared -mrtd -o b.dll; g++ a.cpp b.dll -lgfortran; ./a.exe`. Weird! In any case your solution works perfectly! Thanks again