# Fortran derived types containing derived types to be accessible from C

Tags: c, pointers, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding, derived-types

As an extension to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543180/fortran-derived-types-containing-pointers-to-be-accessible-from-c), I have derived types which have as members derived types themselves. Example below:

```
module simple
use  iso_c_binding

TYPE SIMPLEF
  INTEGER :: A
  INTEGER, POINTER :: B, C(:)
END TYPE SIMPLEF

TYPE COMPLEXF
  INTEGER :: X
  TYPE (SIMPLEF) :: Y
END TYPE COMPLEXF
end module simple
```

The aim is, as in the post above, to have similar derived types in C and to be able to pass values back and forth to Fortran. The solution can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28551786/4572020). However here it's not just a derived type, it is a derived type with a member which is a derived type itself. Would I need to create for COMPLEXF, subroutines for each member of Y, i.e. SETY_A, QUERYY_A, SETY_B, QUERYY_BSIZE, SQUERYY_B etc.? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same approach can be used.  What's best depends on what you think is the best way for your C clients to interact with your Fortran objects.  Some thought should be put into this before you write too much code.

As presented, the existence of the `y` component is a detail that the C code probably doesn't need to care about - rather than calling the procedure `sety_a` you could just name it `set_a`.

If there are going to be many operations on the component of the `COMPLEXF` type and you want to avoid a level of indirection, or if there are many such components of `COMPLEXF` of the same type, then you can use the C address of the subobject that corresponds to that component as an opaque handle.

For the sake of example, alter the `GetHandle` and `ReleaseHandle` procedures in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543180/fortran-derived-types-containing-pointers-to-be-accessible-from-c/28551786#28551786) to work with the `COMPLEXF` type as the top level type (that is - substitute `COMPLEXF` for all the appearances of `SIMPLEF` in that answer).  You could then write a `QueryYHandle` procedure or similar, along the lines of:

```
FUNCTION QueryYHandle(handle) RESULT(y_handle)
  TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: handle
  TYPE(C_PTR) :: y_handle
  TYPE(COMPLEXF), POINTER :: p
  !***
  CALL C_F_POINTER(handle, p)
  y_handle = C_LOC(p%y)
END FUNCTION QueryYHandle
```

Now you can work with the handle to the `SIMPLEF` subobject directly - using the exact same Query*/Set* procedures as in the linked answer.

There's no need to write a procedure to deallocate the object nominated by the `y_handle` in this case, because the lifetime of the subobject associated with the `y` component is determined by the lifetime of the object that has that subobject - that subobject will go away when ReleaseHandle for the `COMPLEXF` super-object is called.

Note that there are no protections in the approach, as outlined above, for the wrong sort of handle to be passed between languages (for example - if the C code accidentally called a procedure intended to work with a `COMPLEXF` handle with a handle that was actually for a `SIMPLEF` object).  If that is problematic then protections can be added, perhaps by bundling a handle type in with the C address in the object used as the opaque handle and checking that handle type before attempting to associate a Fortran pointer with the object nominated by the C address.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So in Fortran I can still change the y SIMPLEF component of  a COMPLEXF variable, and then C will get back the updated component using the C_LOC arrangement. I am guessing that if I wanted I could still access the subcomponents of y in the C side at this stage, or I could just equate y (already obtained back with C_LOC)  to another SIMPLEF type variable with updated values in C.